# how to remove href attribute from element in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

There is jsx element, all I need is remove 'href' attribute based on a value,

code below throws parsing error,

```
 <a
                  className={`nav-link ${item === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
                  data-mdb-toggle="tab"
                  {...{item.focus ? `href == '#active_tab'`}} // Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","                  role="tab"
                  aria-selected={item.name === active}
                >
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Created a sample example here for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wright-2ho99?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your condition is not correct. change to below:

```
{... item.focus ? {href: '#active_tab'} : {}}
```

Comment: pls check it now

Comment: yes it works, I will accept it when stackoverflow is let me,(waiting for allowed time is done), thanks!